# A context-based simple harmonic question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator

The question I'm trying to understand is part b) of this: [image]

For part a) I calculated the angular velocity to be $\pi$ rad$s^{-1}$ by solving $T=\frac{2\pi}{ω}$, where $T=2$s. Then I used $v_{max}=aω$ and found $a=\frac{3}{\pi}$. 
Now, regarding part b) my plan was to find the time taken for the particle to travel from the equilibrium position to the lowest point and find the time taken for the particle to travel 5m below the pier (from the equilibrium position) and then subtract these two times to get the time taken to go from the lowest point to 5m below the pier. 
Since the highest point is 3m from the pier, then 5m below the pier must be 2m down from the highest point. The equilibrium position is $a$ metres down from the highest position so it's $\frac{3}{\pi}=0.955m$ down from the highest point. Since $2>0.955$ then 2m from the highest point must be $2-0.955=1.045m$ below the equilibrium position. However, since $1.045>0.955$ this means that 2m below the highest point is actually past the lowest point so it wouldn't be possible to calculate a time from the equilibrium point to the point 2m below the highest point. I've been trying to find the flaw in my reasoning and I've not been successful so I'm wondering if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:  the boat takes 2 seconds to travel from its highest point to its lowest point.  How much time does it take to make a full cycle and return to its highest point?  Which one of these amounts of time is the period of the oscillation?

Comment: Yeah it works out with the new amplitude.